# Be able to lookup for diferent values within the same cell, for every cell that meets a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I need to be able to lookup for diferent values within the same cell and then search for every value of the cell in every column of another document and return me the value that corresponds,

I came up with the following formula to be able to detect and return just the searched value

[image: image 1]

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C13,TEXTBEFORE(C13,C12,1,1,1,""),"",1),TEXTAFTER(C13,C12,1,1,1,""),"",1)`

This basically compares if the searched text is eliminated from the original text, then it subtracts the rest of the text that is not the searched value and returns me the searched value,

From that I need to be able to link and search for a corresponding value, well, that's no problem since i can just use vlookup for the returned value in the 1st formula, I ended up with something like this,

```
IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER("/"&D300&"/"),UPPER("/"&'FCC-ID-02-VA'!B18&"/"),""))<LEN(UPPER(CONCAT(D300)))+2,,TEXTAFTER(D300,'FCC-ID-02-VA'!B18,1,1,1,""),"",1),'Sheet1'!$A:$AY,51,0)),"")
```

***This is where the fun begins***

This works fine for a predefined cell, like in this case the cell 'FCC-ID-02-VA'!B18, but i need to be able to search in every cell of the column B (or multiple ranges), not just the cell B18,

Not just that, I also need to verify, for every searched cell (i.e.'FCC-ID-02-VA'!B:B), search within a chain pool (i.e.SDAA000001/SDDB000009/SDCD000001/SDDB000017/SDDB000023/SDDC000004/SDDE000001/SDDE000015/SDDF000008/SDDG000004/SDDH000001/SDDH000009) if a searched value (i.e.SDDB000009) is contained and then return me a corresponding value,

**To make it clearer, here is an example of what must happen**

If I input multiple S values like this
[image: FCC-ID-02-VA]

I need to verify if they are contained in the cell D300, if one of them is contained, a value corresponding to that specific S key must show up in the cell G300. This also needs to be true for cells D299 and G299 and so on.
[image]

[image: Sheet1]

Note: there will be no "duplication" of the S keys, i.e. you will never find in FCC-ID-02-VA, both SDDB000007 and SDDB000004 inputed

Basically, this formula works

```
IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(UPPER("/"&D300&"/"),UPPER("/"&'FCC-ID-02-VA'!B18&"/"),""))<LEN(UPPER(CONCAT(D300)))+2,,TEXTAFTER(D300,'FCC-ID-02-VA'!B18,1,1,1,""),"",1),'Sheet1'!$A:$AY,51,0)),"")
```

but it's limited to search only in 1 cell whereas i need to search in every B:B cells and check for every value in it and if found return me a corresponding value.

THANKS A LOT, I've been trying to solve this problem for almost 3 days :c

Comment: Not sure if I understand the second part. It's not focused to one problem, it seems to be multiple. But in the start this could be helpfull: `=LET(t,TEXTSPLIT(C13,"/"),XLOOKUP(C12,t,t,"not found"))` or `=MID(C13,SEARCH("/"&C12&"/","/"&C13&"/"),LEN(C12))`

Comment: It's better to focus your question to your problem and post sample data as markdown table https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables